# .NET/C# dictionary locking protocols

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to precisely understand locking and concurrency issues with .NET's Dictionary collection - not ConcurrentDictionary. Suppose I have a Dictionary defined as key=string, value=SomeOtherRandomClass.

1. Must the entire dictionary be write-locked during a call to TryGetValue("abc")?
2. If it is possible to guarantee that no keys will be added/deleted during the call to TryGetValue - does the entire dictionary still need to be write-locked?
3. Given a successful call to TryGetValue, must the entire dictionary be locked while the corresponding value (SomeOtherClass) is modified? Or just that specific key, so that two people can't update the same (SomeOtherClass) simultaneously.

I believe the most logical answers are yes, no, and then no and yes to #3. But I'd like to be absolutely sure. But I can imagine implementations where the answer to #1 would be no.

Comment: The easiest solution is to just use `ConcurrentDictionary`. What is you specific problem with using that rather than trying to reinvent the wheel? 1) Yes. 2) No, but the way you guarantee that situation is _by locking the entire dictionary_ (see 1). 3) That kinda depends on what you are trying to do and is actually something that `ConcurrencyDictionary` wouldn't help you with.

Comment: I think yes, no, no-but. In a concurrent environment, the whole dictionary must be write-locked for pretty much any lookup (but multiple concurrent lookups can occur), and read/write locked for any write operations. Once you've gotten the object out of the dictionary, for making changes to that object, you would only need to lock access to that specific object, though another thread could replace the key and remove it from the dictionary entirely. None of this is guarenteed, by the API, though. Using ConcurrentDictionary is the only way to be sure you're safe.

Comment: Did you read what the documentation says for that type about how it can and cannot be accessed from multiple threads?  It specifically answers all of these questions.

Comment: I agree with @MattBurland. If you are asking these questions, you should be using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score -1):

> Must the entire dictionary be write-locked during a call to TryGetValue("abc")?

Yes, because the dictionary's implementation is not thread-safe.

> If it is possible to guarantee that no keys will be added/deleted during the call to TryGetValue - does the entire dictionary still need to be write-locked?

No, it is not possible and yes, it still needs to be write locked. I don't know what "the entire dictionary" means... you need an exclusive lock that prevents two threads from executing code within the same dictionary. This is because the dictionary's implementation is not thread-safe.

> Given a successful call to TryGetValue, must the entire dictionary be locked while the corresponding value (SomeOtherClass) is modified? Or just that specific key, so that two people can't update the same (SomeOtherClass) simultaneously.

If you are modifying the value itself (e.g. you calling `dictionary[key] = value`) then yes it must be locked. If the value is a reference type, and you are not modifying the reference but simply modifying the object that is being referenced, the dictionary need not be locked, because you are not executing any of the dictionary's code, which is not thread safe.

Comment: But the method *is* guaranteed to be safe.

Answer (score -2):

`Dictionary` is not designed with multithreading in mind. *Every* operation on a `Dictionary` instance (both read and write operations) must be locked (ideally on the `Dictionary`'s `SyncRoot` property) if it will be accessed by multiple threads, or you risk corrupting the `Dictionary`. There is no facility for locking just one particular key.

However, the `Dictionary` doesn't care about the internals of its *values*, so you once you have obtained a value, you don't need to keep the `Dictionary` locked while reading or modifying the value itself - unless multiple threads will be accessing each value too (but then you can possibly get away with locking just that value). This all depends on the requirements of your application, but you'd need to do the same work with `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Also note that `ConcurrentDictionary` only protects *individual* operations. If two threads try to get a value for a certain key, and update that key's value to be one more than before, you'd still have a race condition without manually having a lock around the read and write operations.

Comment: OK, I do see that, but if the physical placement of your desired record is determined by applying a hash function to the key - and if the address of your target value cannot change, and I don't see how it can - then I don't see how inserting/deleting other keys can move the address of your target record.

Comment: @lhs Other mutations of the dictionary can result in the backing array needing to be resized, resulting in all of the data moving to a new location.

Comment: OK, thank you Servy, that I understand. But then that implies - if the backing array can be resized any time - that if I have the following logic:

Comment: oops, sorry.  Suppose (1) TryGetValue succeeds, and I have my desired key and value. Now suppose for sake of argument (2) I have to do ten minutes of computation on (SomeOtherClass), the value. If all of the data could move, then that implies I have to keep the entire dictionary locked for the entire ten minutes, no?

Comment: @lhs: The data that would move around inside the `Dictionary` during a resizing is just the _references_ to your values - the values themselves are unaffected. So you don't _inherently_ have to hold the lock while processing a value (after you have obtained it, while under a lock, from the `Dictionary`).

Comment: @lhs: However, if multiple threads might read the same value, make some computation based on the value, and write back a new value to the same key, you'll need a lock throughout that operation. If you don't need to replace the value, but just modify the value itself, you can instead take out a lock on the value if there's a risk that multiple threads might try to modify the same value.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset But if the reference to a value, say SomeClass.SomeArbitraryIntegerField, changes at exactly the wrong instant - in the middle of an assignment statement, say - how can you not have a problem?

Comment: to clarify - the reference changes because of an external (to your code) operation, and the assignment statement is in your application code

Comment: @lhs: You can't have a reference directly to a primitive value or a struct, only to an object (which might in turn contain primitive values or structs). If your value type is primitive or a struct, your `Dictionary` is actually holding _copies_ of those values (although each copy will, I think, automatically be "boxed" inside an object so that the `Dictionary` can have a reference to the copy). The things that are being stored and moved around by a `Dictionary` are the references, so a resizing will _not_ affect the values in any way that is visible to you.

Comment: @lhs: Specifically, if you do `dict[key] = someObject.SomeArbitraryIntegerField;`, your dict is now holding a copy of that integer. Doing `someObject.SomeArbitraryIntegerField++;` will not affect the value in `dict[key]`, and doing `dict[key]++;` will not affect `someObject.SomeArbitraryIntegerField` (as I understand, it won't even affect the first copy; it'll create a new boxed integer and reassign the key to it).

Comment: @lhs: ...but if your value is an object, the `Dictionary` will contain a _reference_ to the value itself: if you do `dict[key] = someIntegerList;`, `dict[key].Add(42);` will be visible through `someIntegerList` and the other way around. However, the list is unaffected by whatever happens inside the `Dictionary`, because the `Dictionary` doesn't contain the list itself, only a reference to it.